# Can SPARQL (Jena) UPDATEs be parameterized by collections of literals (instead of literals)?

Tags: java, sparql, jena

Can I call a parameterized SPARQL UPDATE (as in Jena's `ParameterizedSparqlString`) to set a property to several e.g. literal values?

For instance, I have:

```
Set<String> object = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("literal1", "literal2"));
```

and would like to use a SPARQL update such as:

```
INSERT { [] property ?object } WHERE {}
```

to build these RDF statements:

```
_:SUBJECT property "literal1" .
_:SUBJECT property "literal2" .
```

Does Jena support this kind or parametrization (the signature of `ParameterizedSparqlString` suggests no) or will I have to build the SPARQL UPDATE by looping over the set and concatenating strings?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can use a collection, but you could simplify the process by doing something like: check how many elements the array has (n); then build your query string like `insert { [] :property ?object values ?object { ?object1 ?object2 ... ?objectn }`, and then use the parameterized SPARQL string to replace each `?objecti` with an element from the collection.  It's a bit kludgy, but you'd still get the effect you're looking for.  (It might need to be `insert { ... } where { values ?object { ?object1 ... ?objectn } }`, though;  I'm not sure offhand.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, that is plan B. (I can make reasonable assumptions on maximum *n* in my application.) If you want to write it up as answer I'll accept it if it shall turn out that there is no better support in Jena.

Comment: Well, the other option that you *might* have, depending on whether you're executing locally or not, is to specify an initial binding set.  I know Jena used to support that in SPARQL 1;  I don't know whether that support continued with SPARQL 1.1 and SPARQL Update.  In that case, you'd create a solution set with the bindings for the objects that you have.  It's like 'jump starting' the WHERE part.  [PARAMETERISED QUERIES WITH SPARQL AND ARQ](http://blog.ldodds.com/2005/11/07/parameterised-queries-with-sparql-and-arq/) is old (2005), but it's an illustration of the idea.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?