# Enter values from a list into a sparql query

Tags: java, list, rdf, sparql

I have the following code:

```
 public static List getSomeReceipes(List ing){
    List list = new ArrayList();

    String log4jConfPath = "C:/Users/Karen/workspace/Jena/src/Tutorial/log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    String ingre = " ";

    try {
        //opening owl file
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Karen/Desktop/Proyecto/bbdd.owl"), null, "TTL");
        //System.out.println(model);
        for(int i=0; i<ing.size(); i++){
            ingre = (String) ing.get(i);
            System.out.println(ingre);
        }
        //create a new query
                 String queryString
                ="PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                +"PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                +"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                +"PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"         
                +"PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                +"SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { "
                +"  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta . "
                +"  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                +"  filter not exists {"
                +"    ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i"
                +"    filter( ?i not in (rec:" + ing + "))"
                +"}"
                +"}";
        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

        //execute the query and obtain results

        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        //print query results
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            //System.out.println(results.getResourceModel());
            //ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out,results, q);
            list.add(results.next());
        }
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Query Failed !");
    }
     System.out.println(list.toString() + "\n");
        return list;      
}
```

I would like to add every element of the list given (ing) into the query. So lets say I have a list like: ing=[Tomato, Cucumber, Salt] The I would like to create a query like this:

```
                 String queryString
                ="PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                +"PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                +"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                +"PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"         
                +"PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                +"SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { "
                +"  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta . "
                +"  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                +"  filter not exists {"
                +"    ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i"
                +"    filter( ?i not in (rec:" + Tomato + ", rec:" + Cucumber + ", rec:" + Salt + "))"
                +"}"
                +"}";
```

Is there anyway to do that? Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of a recent question... (searching)

Comment: Which question? Can you put the link here please?

Comment: That's why I said "searching".  I hadn't found it yet.  Anyhow, I was thinking of [Can SPARQL (Jena) UPDATEs be parameterized by collections of literals (instead of literals)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27822769/1281433)

Comment: Ahh sorry, I will check that one! thanks

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about.  That question doesn't have any answers either, so even if you'd found it, it would only be so much help.  However, the comments there may be helpful.

Comment: I will try to find out how to do it and as soon as I do i will post it here! txs!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get parameters from a JSP to a SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095778/get-parameters-from-a-jsp-to-a-sparql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your list is a simple List of Strings, this becomes just basic Java programming, and you can very easily do this by writing a method that takes a `List<String>` as input, and outputs the list as a string in SPARQL syntax. For example:

```
String convertToSPARQLList(List<String> list) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("(");
    for(String item: list) {
         sb.append("rec:" + item);
         sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2); // remove last comma and whitespace
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

and then use that method in your query construction:

```
 String queryString = 
         ....
   + "filter( ?i not in " + convertToSPARQLList(in) + ")"
   + " }" 
   + "}";
```